# toggle password/text with javascript only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to change the following code to javascript only:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fa-eye, .fa-eye-slash').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('fa-eye fa-eye-slash');

        var input=$(this).parent().find('input');

        if(input.attr('type')=='password') {
            input.attr('type', 'text');
        }else input.attr('type', 'password');
    });
});
```

What is does is when you click in an "eye icon" it changes that icon to "eye-slash icon" and changes the password field within the same div to text, so basically toggle password/text.

Since this is currently the only javascript I'm using, I thought it would be overkill to include jQuery or ZeptoJS only for this and this can probably be done with a few lines of javascript.

Please notice: this needs to be applied to multiple fields, that is why I opted not to use ID.

Comment: Please post your HTML so we can test your code properly

Comment: For future reference, [YouMightNotNeedjQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) is a good resource to show equivalent vanilla JS approaches to common jQuery code.

Comment: @AdamPearson I also do not have a sure info about the HTML vespino has, however, I have written a testable snippet. I believe you could use the HTML part as a starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the corrections made to make it work with no jQuery and just relying on vanilla JS and Web API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/):

- `.addEventListener()` to add bubbling event handlers to the elements
- `DOMContentLoaded` event instead of `$(document).ready()`
- `.querySelectorAll()` and `.querySelector()` to select elements instead of using the `$` function
- `.classList.toggle()` instead of `.toggleClass()`
- `event.target` instead of `$(this)`
- `.getAttribute()` and `.setAttribute()` instead of `attr()`
- `.forEach()` to iterate over the array of returned elements

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('.fa-eye, .fa-eye-slash')    
    .forEach( el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', event =>{        
        const trigger = event.target;        
        trigger.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
        trigger.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
        
        const input = trigger.parentNode.querySelector('input');         
        if (input.getAttribute('type') == 'password')
          input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        else
          input.setAttribute('type', 'password');    
      });
    });
});
```

```css
i{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div>
  <input type="password">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <input type="password">
  <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with normal vanilla JS means, see this snippet:

```js
function load() {
    for (let fa of document.querySelectorAll('.fa-eye, .fa-eye-slash')) {
        fa.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.target.classList.toggle('fa-eye');
            e.target.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');

            let input = e.target.parentNode.querySelectorAll('input');

            for (let item of input) {
                if (item.type === 'password') item.type = 'text';
                else item.type = 'password';
            }
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', load);
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="password" value="foo">
    <input type="test" value="bar">
    <div class='fa-eye' style="background-color: green;">CLICK ME</div>
</div>
```

Note that jQuery is also Javascript, albeit, Javascript is not necessarily jQuery.